# R: Sum values that are in different parts of vector

Tags: r, sum

I have a number of vectors consisting of 1s and 0s, such as:

```
[1] x <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
```

I would like to count the number of consecutive 1s at different parts of these sequences, and in this instance end up with:

```
[1] 2 1
```

I have considered using something like strsplit to split the sequence where there are zeros, though it is a numeric vector so strsplit won't work and ideally I don't want to change back and forth between numeric and character format.

Is there another, simpler, solution to this? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you use a numeric value, I think you need to work with strings.

Comment: @Sotos Sorry about that. I am dealing with a vector and have edit my response.

Comment: @Cath Thanks, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split up the value into a vector and use `rle` like this:

With your original value

```
x <- 11001

temp <- rle(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split="")))

temp$lengths[temp$values == 1]
[1] 2 1
```

It's a bit simpler when starting with the vector as you don't have to use `strsplit` and `unlist`.

```
x <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)

temp <- rle(x)

temp$lengths[temp$values == 1]
[1] 2 1
```

Comment: Not necessary for this case but `temp$values[temp$values != 0] * temp$lengths[temp$values != 0]` would probably be more general

Comment: @db Right. That would also work in the case of non-binary vectors.